# Automate and capture login prompt through perl's expect

Tags: perl, expect.pm

I'm trying to automate a login prompt in Perl

I'm using `SSHGetCredentials('login_prompt' => 1)` to generate a login prompt which is a function of perl's `Expect::SSH` library

This is how my code looks like, here `REST::Client->getCredentials()` internally calls `SSHGetCredentials('login_prompt' => 1)` which would call a login prompt and return the entered userID and password.

```
use Expect;
my $command = "perl -e 'use REST::Client; REST::Client->getCredentials()'";
my $exp = Expect->spawn($command) || die "i am done";
$exp->expect(undef, 'Login on Remote:');
$exp->send("user\n");
$exp->expect(undef, 'Password of user:');
$exp->send("12345\n");
```

Now I want to verify whether user name or password is what I have passed, so I want to capture them and compare.

How can I capture them?

I tried this:

```
use Expect;
my $command = "perl -e 'use REST::Client; \$tmp = REST::Client->getCredentials();print \$tmp->{'username'};print \" \";print \$tmp->{'password'};'";
my $exp = Expect->spawn($command) || die "i am done";
$exp->expect(undef, 'Login on Remote:');
$exp->send("user\n");
$exp->expect(undef, 'Password of user:');
$exp->send("12345\n");
my $value = $exp->expect(1);
```

but `$value` has nothing and `$exp->expect(1)` just prints the values in STDOUT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's the best way but it works

```
use Expect;
my $command = "perl -e 'use REST::Client; \$tmp = REST::Client->getCredentials();print \$tmp->{'username'};print \" \";print \$tmp->{'password'};'";
my $exp = Expect->spawn($command) || die "i am done";
$exp->expect(undef, 'Login on Remote:');
$exp->send("user\n");
$exp->expect(undef, 'Password of user:');
$exp->send("12345\n");
if ($exp->expect(undef,'-re','user 12345') == 1) {
    print "matched\n";
}
```